# Split strings from table by space into separate columns

Tags: ms-access, split, vba

I process tables in MS ACCESS 2016 and I have one column in a table which is text (string) like this example: D1 na 256km směr Břeclav.

I need to split that text into separate columns for every word so I can prepare data to delete some words and so on. I have already tried some examples in VBA for Access but it didn't work.

I need to Split them. Does anybody know how? The Split function doesn't work in an SQL query, and I don't know how to properly do it in VBA.

Comment: Add some code when you post a question. or state your query which you have used so far.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar case recently.
To be able to run split in query design create a function in a standard module to be able to call it from the expression builder.

```
Public Function ESplit(Pstring As String, PSeparator As String, PIndex As Integer) As String
    '************************************
    'Use Split in Expression Builder
    'PString - String containing source to be separated
    'PSeparator - String containing delimitator
    'PIndex - Element of the source to be returned, starts at 0
    '************************************
    ESplit = Split(Pstring, PSeparator)(PIndex)
End Function
```

Then assign columns that you want to have the words with expressions calling this function.

Source
D1 na 256km směr Břeclav.

Expr1: ESplit(Source," ",0)
This will yield D1